# Palabras repetidas en Python

Tags: python, array, string

anteriormente hice un ejercicio de esto. Constaba de: Escribir una funcion que cuente la cantidad de veces q se repite una palabra.
En si está hecho, pero quiero q el arreglo donde estan las palabras q encontré repetidas no se repitan, valga la redundancia. Es decir si la palabra "hola" sale tres veces, solo salga la palabra hola una vez en el arreglo de palabras repetidas.

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
    cadena = "Esto esto esto este texto. Es una prueba de texto"
cadena = cadena.lower()
lista = []
j = ""
for i in cadena:
    if not i == " ":
        if not i == ".":
            if not i == ",":
                j += i
    else:
        lista.append(j)    
        j=""
if j:
    lista.append(j)

array = []    
for i in lista:
    n = lista.count(i)
    if n > 1:
            array.append(i)
    else:
        pass


        

print(array)
```

Comment: Si quieres aprovechar el código que ya tienes hecho en vez de reescribirlo para hacerlo de otra forma, podrías simplemente hacer al final `array=list(set(array))`. Al convertir tu lista a conjunto se eliminan automáticamente los duplicados (aunque también te cambiaría el orden de los elementos y no sé si eso sería un problema para tu caso). También puedes cambiar tu `if n>1` por `if n>1 and i not in array:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución usando expresiones regulares para extraer las palabras puras, sin signos ortográficos pegados, sólo las letras. La expresión regular es "([a-z]+)".

El método `findall` aplica el patrón a la cadena y devuelve un iterador que recorre todas las palabras encontradas. Ordenamos las palabras con `sorted`, y sólo nos resta encontrar los duplicados.

Examinamos cada palabra contra la anterior. Si es igual, está repetida. Si no está en la lista de salida, la agregamos.

```
import re

patron = re.compile("([a-z]+)")

def sacar_repetidas(cadena):
    palabra_anterior = ''
    repetidas = []
    for palabra in sorted(patron.findall(cadena.lower())):
        if palabra == palabra_anterior and palabra not in repetidas:
            repetidas.append(palabra)
        palabra_anterior = palabra
    return repetidas

tests = [
    "Esto esto esto este texto. Es una prueba de texto",
    "Esto. esto, ¿esto? =este=. Otra _prueba_ de _texto_ con texto"]

for test in tests:
    print("Texto:     ", test)
    print("Repetidas: ", sacar_repetidas(test))
```

produce:

```
Texto:      Esto esto esto este texto. Es una prueba de texto
Repetidas:  ['esto', 'texto']
Texto:      Esto. esto, ¿esto? =este=. Otra _prueba_ de _texto_ con texto
Repetidas:  ['esto', 'texto']
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de esta manera

```
cadena = cadena.lower()

#remplazamos estos caracteres
cadena = cadena.replace(",","")
cadena = cadena.replace(".","")

#seoaramos la cadena 
cadena = cadena.split(" ")

nuevo = []
#recorremos la cadena 
for p in cadena:
    if p not in nuevo:
         nuevo.append(p)
```

**Probamos**
`print(nuevo)`

**Salida**
`['esto', 'este', 'texto', 'es', 'una', 'prueba', 'de']`
Si quieres que esto salga como una sola cadena, utiliza la función `.join()` de esta forma `print(" ".join(nuevo))`